# How to set the Jenkins build name based on some conditions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wish to set the build name  based on some condition.

Eg:

```
if the branch name( input parameter)= development 
then build name= development

if the branch name = master then build name= master.
```

I can able to set the build name by using build name setter plugin but i need this based on condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you use Free Style jobs, then you can use the `Groovy` plugin to execute arbitrary groovy code which has access to the Java structures for the build and Jenkins.

Simply add an `Execute system Groovy script`step and enter your code which determines the name, then use `build.setDisplayName()` to set the name.

So similar to your example, here is a name setter which sets the name depending on the value of build parameter `branch_name`:

```
if (build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("branch_name").equals('master')) {
    build.setDisplayName("Master build #${build.getNumber()}")
} else if (build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("branch_name").equals('development')) {
    build.setDisplayName("Development build #${build.getNumber()}")
} else {
    build.setDisplayName("Other build #${build.getNumber()}")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> if the branch name( input parameter) = development  then build name=
>   development

Assuming you are providing the branch name as a parameter and want to set the build name as the same using the [name setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin), you should be able to configure it.

[image: parameter config section]

You can use the same parameter name as environment variable in the setter plugin as **`${ENV,var="my-special-branch"}`**

[image: setter plugin section]

Comment: This works, but when the jobs is a Pipeline, don't exist the option to build a name

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's way easier than the Groovy script thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set build name to a job from a parameter, you can use

`currentBuild.displayName = "${nameOfYourParameter}"`

**Job Configuration**

[image]

**Buil job with parameters**

[image]

**Build History**

[image]

Ref: [How to set build name in Pipeline job?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220860347-How-to-set-build-name-in-Pipeline-job-)